# Superfish adding hover class to parent item in Concrete5 Edit Mode

Tags: jquery, css, hover, superfish, concrete5

I'm development a website on Concrete5 CMS. I've set up a superfish menu and all is working as it should... when I'm not in 'Edit Mode'.

Here's my code:

```
$('.breadcrumb-nav .inner > ul').superfish({
    hoverClass:    'sfHover',          // the class applied to hovered list items
    delay:         500,                // the delay in milliseconds that the mouse can remain outside a submenu without it closing
    animation:     {opacity:'show'},   // an object equivalent to first parameter of jQuery’s .animate() method. Used to animate the submenu open
    animationOut:  {opacity:'hide', height: 'toggle'},   // an object equivalent to first parameter of jQuery’s .animate() method Used to animate the submenu closed
    speed:         'fast',           // speed of the opening animation. Equivalent to second parameter of jQuery’s .animate() method
    speedOut:      'fast',             // speed of the closing animation. Equivalent to second parameter of jQuery’s .animate() method
    cssArrows:     true               // set to false if you want to remove the CSS-based arrow triangles
});
```

--

When I'm not editing the page superfish works like so:

Hovering over `.breadcrumb-nav .inner > ul > li` adds the class `sfHover` to `.breadcrumb-nav .inner > ul > li`. - Just as one would expect

--

When I'm in edit mode, for some reason this happens:

Hovering over `.breadcrumb-nav .inner > ul > li` adds the class `sfHover` to `.breadcrumb-nav .inner > ul`. - The parent item instead of the individual list item.

--

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the issue. I'm not able to provide a link at the moment, but I will do so later when I have the website online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but it's possible that a class name you're using is also in use by some of the stuff C5 adds when in edit mode? Maybe try changing your class name (in your nav menu markup, your CSS, and the superfish initialization javascript code) -- e.g. change `.breadcrumb-nav` to `.site-breadcrumb-nav` (just an example). C5 is usually pretty good about not polluting classnames (most C5-added things are prefixed with `ccm-`) but every now and then something might slip through.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this could be the issue in my case. I double checked just in case. I have a link to the dev copy online now. If you're interested in taking a look I could supply you with a link. Let me know.